# SQLite: How to enable explain plan with the Python API?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-execution-plan, peewee

I'm using Python (and Peewee) to connect to a SQLite database. My data access layer (DAL) is a mix of peewee ORM and SQL-based functions. I would like to enable EXPLAIN PLAN for all queries upon connecting to the database and toggle it via configuration or CLI parameter ... how can I do that using the Python API?

```
from playhouse.db_url import connect

self._logger.info("opening db connection to database, creating cursor and initializing orm model ...")
self.__db = connect(url)
# add support for a REGEXP and POW implementation
# TODO: this should be added only for the SQLite case and doesn't apply to other vendors.
self.__db.connection().create_function("REGEXP", 2, regexp)
self.__db.connection().create_function("POW", 2, pow)
self.__cursor = self.__db.cursor()
self.__cursor.arraysize = 100
# what shall I do here to enable EXPLAIN PLANs?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a feature of the sqlite interactive shell. To get the query plans, you will need to explicitly request it. This is not quite straightforward with Peewee because it uses parameterized queries. You can get the SQL executed by peewee in a couple of ways.

```
# Print all queries to stderr.
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('peewee')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Or for an individual query:

```
query = SomeModel.select()
sql, params = query.sql()

# To get the query plan:
curs = db.execute_sql('EXPLAIN ' + sql, params)
print(curs.fetchall())  # prints query plan
```

Comment: thank you! this is already a working solution. I was still hoping to be able to set something at connection / cursor level and output explain plans without having to prepend EXPLAIN to every query in the code ... otherwise I will have to come up with a generic solution to toggle the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Do you really have that many different queries you need to analyze? Presumably they will mostly follow the same plan or an easily-inferrable plan.